# Unit testing a state machine with all possible transitions?

Tags: java, state-machine

I have a state machine implemented as this data structure under the hood:

```
Map<State, Map<State, boolean>>
```

The idea being you use the original state as the input to lookup the list of possible target states. Then you lookup the target state in that embedded map, and if it's there, a possible transition exists.

My problem is unit testing all possible transitions, such that if you give the test some input that will throw an error (an invalid state transition), then the test should fail if you have not included *all* of the states.

My test looks something like this:

```
public void invalid_state_transition() {
    State originalState = State0;
    List<State> targetStates = List.of(
        State1, 
        State2, 
        ...
    )

    for (targetState : targetStates) {
        TransitionToTargetState(originalState, targetState)
    }
}
```

How would I go about doing this? Or am I thinking about the problem in the wrong way?

Comment: I don't see that you actually verify the result of each state transition. Seems to me that you should have two lists of states, one for valid transitions and one for invalid transitions. The valid transitions should have some verification of success. The invalid ones should have a verification that they throw.

Comment: Yep, this is just an example test for invalid State0 transitions (should've named the test better for this example!). The tests themselves run as expected. But my problem is that if I omit a state from either list, the tests still pass which I don't want. Although I don't know if there's any way around it with the way I've designed it.

Comment: That sort of thing would probably be caught by using a coverage tool with your unit test.